# copy directory and its contents without using xcopy or robocopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

`xcopy` and `robocopy` are not working when I try to transfer files to a remote drive, so i'm restricted to using `del` and `copy` until I can figure that out.

Here is what I have so far:

```
del /q y:\OPENcontrol\targetDir
for /d %%x in (y:\OPENcontrol\targetDir\*) do @rd /s /q "%%x"

copy c:\Users\CNC\share y:\OPENcontrol\targetDir
```

How can I copy folders and their contents without using `xcopy` or `robocopy`?

Edit: This is on a CNC machine that is transferring files to its OPENcontrol module. The code needs to work within the limitations of the OSAI controller. A good example is that `do (mkdir "destination\%%i" copy "%%i\*" "destination\%%i")` had to execute in two separate loop commands, one for `mkdir` and one for `copy`

Comment: you would need to use a for loop and recursively search each directory in source, create it in destination and copy it's content... something similar to `for /d /r "sourcedir" %%i in (*) do (mkdir "destination\%%i" copy "%%i\*" "destination\%%i")`

Comment: @double-beep I did not, I gave example batch code, there should be newline between mkdir and copy commands.

Comment: @double-beep yep. I cannot post an answer now as I am on my phone and typically do not like posting answers if I cannot test before I post.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard well, I don't think it will work. `md` command will make a folder with `destination\full\path\to\that\\folder` and even `%%~ni` won't work as because it might be in a subdirectory. Thinking of another solution!

Comment: @Gerhard Brnard I made some small changes and it worked: `for /d /r "c:\Users\Nil\share" %%i in (*) do (mkdir "c:\Users\Nil\targetDir\%%~nxi" copy "%%i\*" "c:\Users\Nil\targetDir\%%~nxi")` post your answer with the above changes and i will accept

Comment: Somehow this reminds me of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)... why should `robocopy` and `xcopy` not work? what exactly did you try using these two commands?

Comment: @Carpk solution won't work if a folder created exists in a subfolder.

Comment: certainly `robocopy` can copy files to/from the network. It even has the option `/Z` option for those files. `xcopy` also has `/Z Copies networked files in restartable mode`. This is definitely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282)

Comment: @phuclv @aschipfl This is on a CNC machine, there are limitations to the OPENcontrol module where I am attempting to copy these files. I even had to break the `do` block into two separate `for` loop commands.

Comment: I don't know what OPENcontrol is but the protocol is the same in robocopy and xcopy so that shouldn't be a problem. The target don't even know how you copy the files

Comment: @double-beep There is a reason I do not post answers when I am unable to test, hence the comment stating _"something similar to"_ ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment (not being 100% working at the time). a Simple for loop will be able to run through each folder, create it and copy its contents. There are better ways, but yes, you said you wanted to use `copy` specifically. So as per your ammended comment:

```
for /d /r "c:\Users\Nil\share" %%i in (*) do (
     mkdir "c:\Users\Nil\targetDir\%%~nxi"
     copy "%%i\*" "c:\Users\Nil\targetDir\%%~nxi"
)
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in the comments: let's say full path to folder is `C:\Users\Nil\share\folder1\folder2`. `folder2` will be made in `C:\Users\Nil\targetDir\folder2`, but it should be `C:\Users\Nil\targetDir\folder2`. Also, folders don't have extension (but if they have `.` system will think they have; this is OK). Also mentioned in the comments this is XY. Flag question and request further information from the OP instead of direct answer.

Comment: @double-beep I do not get the reason to flag the question. I have enough reputation to vote on a question if I feel it is off topic. Again, I posted the answer on my phone based on the response to my comment from the OP. I will go through the answer and edit where I feel it needs editing when I have time during the day.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the author accepted it because there wasn't subfolders in the folder he had to move.